# Determine the filled julia set for the mapping $~f(z)=αz~$ where $~α~$ is complex constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've tried to solve this problem and don't understand where to begin with Julia set problems. Can you help with this?

> Determine the filled julia set for the mapping $~f(z)=αz~$ where $~α~$ is complex constant.

Comment: What is your definition of Julia set?

Comment: "The filled Julia set of polynomial function f is 
{`z_{0}` : the orbit of `z_{0}` in the map f is bounded}.

Julia set is the edge of filled Julia set."

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* We have $f^n(z_0)=\alpha^n z_0$. What can you say about bounded orbits?

Comment: Thanks! I think (and hope) I understood your hint. The problem is that in our material, there's no examples for Julia set problems and the definitions are poor.